# Finding unit normal vector

Tags: derivatives, vectors

I have posted this question before just regarding the unit tangent vector. But my friends and I have different answers when it comes to the unit normal vector of this parametric curve when $t=\pi$:

A cycloid is given by $C:[0,2\pi] \rightarrow R^2$

[image]

I just differentiate $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ two times and plug in $\pi$, like this.

$x'(t)=b-b\cos t$

$x''(t)=b\sin t$

$y'(t)=b\sin t$

$y''(t)=b\cos t$

And then the normal vector must be $[0,-b]$ and the unit normal vector is  $[0,-1]$. I'm I wrong?

Comment: Looks right to me!

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! I will stick to my answer then !